# Caller for abort() is unknown in the backtrace, any suggestions to debug this

Tags: c++, c, gdb, abort, raise

I'm trying to debug one of my crashes and it seems to be caused by the abort raised from some where, and my gdb is not giving the caller details instead just shows few frames in the callstack. Any suggestions would be most welcome in debugging this issue.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76453fc4 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.0
#1  0x7644d654 in abort () from /lib/libc.so.0
#2  0x7644cc4c in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.0
warning: GDB can't find the start of the function at 0x7644cc4a.
```

Comment: Try `valgrind`, might give you a clue where you're corrupting your program's state.

Comment: Have you compiled with the -g option ?

Comment: Yes, i have -g enabled in the buildroot. But still i don't get the full call stack. I need to check whether valgrind is ported and tested in my buildroot.

Comment: It could be a corrupted stack as well.

Comment: ??? means gdb is not able to read the symbol information; Hence you should build your application + the underlying libraries etc, using -g option & then try to run GDB again. This should get you going.

Answer (score 1):

Use `valgrind`. It will be useful to compile with debug information (`-g` using GCC) before using `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

The truncated stack trace you get is *most often* caused by a mismatch between `libc.so.6` that you used when looking at the `core`, and the one that was used to produce that `core`.

Given that you talk about buildroot, it seems likely that that might have happened.

You *are* debugging a `core` dump, and not a live process, right?